# how to read and write contacts permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contacts

I have managed to read contacts however I want to write contacts as well as read them. Could anyone please advise how I am able to manage to do these two task,
Error Message.

Please see my code below for the READ_CONTACTS I want to extend it to WRITE_CONTACTS as well.

```
       // Called when the user is performing an action which requires the app to read the
    // user's contacts
    public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
        // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
        // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
        // in Marshmallow
        // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
        // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
            }

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    // Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
        if (requestCode == READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ContentResolver reContentResolverol = getContentResolver();
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor phone = reContentResolverol.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                    null,
                    null);
            while (phone.moveToNext()) {
                String usernumber = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                phone1.setText(usernumber);
                name1.setText(username);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, both [in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html) and [at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Also, please note that `managedQuery()` was deprecated **six years ago**, and it was a bad idea before then as well. Please use newer techniques (e.g., `CursorLoader`).

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: The simplest solution, tactically, is for you to change your `targetSdkVersion` (typically in `app/build.gradle`) to 22. Then you will not need to deal with runtime permissions. Beyond that, I cannot advise you unless you explain, **in detail**, what you do not understand.

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: Well, `WRITE_CALENDAR` is not what you want. You need to check for, and request, the runtime permission before using the API that needs the permission. Since requesting the permission displays a dialog and delivers a result asynchronously, you might want to do that before making the `startActivityForResult()` call that triggers the `onActivityResult()` that you show in your question.

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: You need to add an `import` statement for `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CONTACTS

Comment: How do I WRITE_CONTACTS  as well as READ_CONTACTS. Please advise

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: You need to call checkSelfPermission() once for each. requestPermissions() takes a String array, so you can request them at the same time.

Comment: I have done this however, I am still not able to. please advise as it is reading contacts, wheres, it is not writing contacts.

Comment: @ElderlyWatch "I have done this" - then post your updated code in your question. The code you've currently posted doesn't request a `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission so it obviously won't be given.